# Can you translate this into ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

So basically, I would like to use ggplot function geom_line + geom_point to create the same plots but with fancier graphics.

```
> a
          V1        V2        V3 
1  0.8224887 0.7882316 0.7596440 
2  0.7892779 0.7604186 0.7409430 
3  0.8254516 0.8257800 0.8014778 
4  0.8268519 0.7887464 0.7887322 
5  0.8226651 0.7981079 0.7934783 


plot(6:10, a$V1, type="l", xlab="Folds", ylab="Accuracy", col="Blue",ylim=c(0.7,0.9))
par(new=TRUE) 
plot(6:10, a$V2, type="l", xlab="Folds", ylab="Accuracy", col="Orange",ylim=c(0.7,0.9))
par(new=TRUE) 
plot(6:10, a$V3, type="l", xlab="Folds", ylab="Accuracy", col="Green",ylim=c(0.7,0.9))
```

My main goal is to get a legend that helps to distinguish each variable.

I tried to plot just the first line:

```
ggplot(data = a)+
  theme_classic()+
  geom_line(aes(x=6:10, y = a$V1, color = "blue"))
```

The problem is that i don't even get the color I want.

Thanks for reading and helping!

Comment: You should pass the color argument outside of aes(). `geom_line(aes(x=6:10, y=a$v1), color = 'blue')`
Note that you can also pass the argument inside the `aes()` function, but it should map to some column in dataframe. Say for example if you have a category column in your dataframe, you can pass `color = category` and ggplot will automatically plot lines with different colors depending on the number of categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

originalData <- tibble(
  V1=c(0.8224887, 0.7892779, 0.8254516, 0.8268519, 0.8226651),
  V2=c(0.7882316, 0.7604186, 0.8257800, 0.7887464, 0.7981079), 
  V3=c(0.7596440, 0.7409430, 0.8014778, 0.7887322, 0.7934783)
)

# ggplot works best if your data is 'tidy'
tidyData <- originalData %>% 
              pivot_longer(cols=c(V1, V2, V3), names_to="Variable") %>% 
              add_column(X=rep(6:10, each=3))

tidyData

tidyData %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=X, y=value, colour=Variable)) +
    geom_line() + 
    theme_classic()
```

Giving

[image]

You can customise your plot from here as you like.

Answer (score 2):

```
library (dplyr)
library (ggplot2)

a <- data.frame(
V1=rnorm(5),
V2=rnorm(5),
V3=rnorm(5),
Folds = 6:10) # make some example data

a %>% 
tidyr::gather(key,value,-Folds) %>% #get data in long format for ggplot
ggplot(.,aes(x = Folds,y = value,y,col = key))+
geom_line() + # add line
geom_point() + # add points
scale_color_manual("My Variables",values = c("blue","orange","green")) + #change colours
theme_classic()
```